# Ghost Char - &lt; Does not exist in the code, but shows in rendered HTML

Tags: html

Take a look at this page: http://jqeedu.tuxfamily.org/test/index.php.
You'll see a `<` between the fieldset and table. Firebug also shows there is a `&lt;` But it is not in the code. I have checked character by character, in Notepad++, notepad, and XVI32. View Page Source in Firefox does not show it either! How could this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 117:

```
<td>Room D</td><<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&
```

Spot the `<<`.  A stray `<` or `>` in the page result is usually due to a tag delimiter typed twice, so a quick find (or find and replace) in the source for `<<` or `>>` catches them.

Comment: Oh thanks! Soon it'd had me go blind. Good point on searching for `<<` or `>>` too.